# super() class does not work in constructor because a constructor must be the first statement in a constructor, but it is

Tags: java

Why does the super() constructor not work in this constructor? It keeps telling me that it has to be the first statement in a constructor, but it does not work even if it´s the first statement.

And I can also not work with it, when it´s the first statement because in my program i have to check first if there is enough cars  and gas left before a car can be sold. Are there any ways how i can solve this? I think I must use this way, our professor told us so.

```
public class PassengerCarTrader extends CarTrader {

    public static final int CAPACITY_AUDI = 4;
    public static final int CAPACITY_BMW = 4;
    public static final int CAPACITY_OPEL = 4;
    public static final int CAPACITY_MERCEDES = 3;


        public void sellCar(int brand){

            super(brand);

        Vehicle soldVehicle=null;

        switch (brand){
        case 1://AUDI

            if (this.audiStock>=1 && this.gasStockLiters>=Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_PASSENGER_CAR){
                this.audiStock = this.audiStock - 1;

            } else {

                System.err.println("Nicht genug AUDI oder Benzin vorhanden");
            }
            break;
        case 2://BMW
            if(this.bMWStock>=1 && this.gasStockLiters>=Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_TRUCK){
                this.bMWStock = this.bMWStock -1;

            } else {
                System.err.println("Nicht genug BMW oder Benzin vorhanden");
            }
            break;
        case 3://MERCEDES
            if (this.mercedesStock>=1 && this.gasStockLiters>=Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_PASSENGER_CAR){
                this.mercedesStock = this.mercedesStock - 1;

            } else {
                System.err.println("Nicht genug Mercedes oder Benzin vorhanden");
            }
            break;
        case 4://OPEL
            if(this.opelStock>=1 && this.gasStockLiters>=Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_TRUCK){
                this.opelStock = this.opelStock -1;


            } else {
                System.err.println("Nicht genug Opel oder Benzin vorhanden");
            }
            break;
        default: soldVehicle=null;

            break;
        }
        }
}
```

This is the main class

```
public abstract class CarTrader {

public static final float CAPACITY_DIESEL_LITERS = 350.f;
public static final float CAPACITY_GAS_LITERS = 180.f;
public static final int CAPACITY_PASSENGER_CARS = 15;
public static final int CAPACITY_TRUCKS = 8;


float gasStockLiters=180.f;
float dieselStockLiters=250.f;
int passengerCarsStock=15;
int trucksStock=5;

int mANStock=4;
int scaniaStock=4;
int audiStock=4;
int bMWStock=4;
int opelStock=4;
int mercedesStock=3;

    public Vehicle sellVehicle(byte vehicleType){

Vehicle soldVehicle=null;


switch (vehicleType){
case VehicleType.TRUCK: 

        trucksStock = trucksStock - 1;
        dieselStockLiters = dieselStockLiters - Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_TRUCK;
        soldVehicle = new Vehicle(VehicleType.TRUCK);
        System.out.println("Fahrzeug(e) erfolgreich verkauft");
break;

case VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR:

        passengerCarsStock = passengerCarsStock - 1;
        gasStockLiters = gasStockLiters - Vehicle.TANK_SIZE_PASSENGER_CAR;
        soldVehicle = new Vehicle(VehicleType.PASSENGER_CAR);
        System.out.println("Fahrzeug(e) erfolgreich verkauft");     
break;
}
    return soldVehicle;
}
```

Comment: The only `super` in your code is `super(brand);` in the `sellCar` method. That *isn't* a constructor.

Comment: And for next time: please always include the exact compiler error or stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You have no constructors in your classes.
[Providing Constructors for Your Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Answer (score 0):

super(brand).... this is not a super constructor call.. rather it is a super method call.
Rename 'sellCar(int brand)'  in PassengerCarTrader to sellVehicle(byte vehicleType)... then super may work in your code..... pont is ...super in your case  will only work if your parent  class has same method name as that of  child class from  where u r calling super